Any resource focusing on choosing the right SPH simulation parameters?
I am a software engineer with no prior experience in numerical and/or physical models (apart from very simple particle simulations). The last few weeks I've been trying to implement a 2D real-time SPH fluid sim based on this paper (Müller et al).
So far, I think that I've reached a stage where all calculations should be correct – calculate density, pressure and viscosity (no surface tension) with their respective kernels adapted for 2D SPH and then integrate with the Leapfrog method. However, what I am struggling to do is to choose the right parameters for the simulation, I think.
Could anyone of you point me to a resource from which I can gain insights into proper parameter tuning? I want to know the intuition behind it. The paper that I am using doesn't focus on that part and my search didn't render any meaningful results apart from this. Thanks!
Current simulation state
